# Using java.sql.Date

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using jdbc to call a sql query "`.... where mydate like '?%'` "
and I want to pass the parameter to the query with:

```
PreparedStatement ps;  
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date.valueOf("2000-01-13"));
```

But this last line is not compiling, and I don't know why. When i enter the date directly into the query above, as in ".. where mydate like '2000-01-13%'", it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the basic compilation error (just remove `new`), I spot 2 serious problems:

1. Given the fact that `LIKE` works, your `mydate` field is apparently of a `varchar` type instead of a fullworthy `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp` type. This is recipe for problems. You should always use the right data type for the information the field holds.
2. `%` cannot be put after preparedstatement placeholder `?`. It has to be set in the value directly. However, this works with `String` values only (and thus `varchar` field types). For a fullworthy `date`, `datetime` and `timestamp`  type you'd rather use `=`, `<`, `>` or `BETWEEN` instead.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Change the data type of the field to be a real `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`, so that you can use the proper SQL syntax such as `WHERE mydate BETWEEN ? AND ?`.
2. Use `preparedStatement.setString(1, "2000-01-13%")` instead and remove those singlequotes around the placeholder `?` as well so that it ends like `WHERE mydate LIKE ?`.

#### See also:

- [Preparedstatement tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [MySQL data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-types.html)

Comment: +1 I was about to recommend BETWEEN since it's clear what they're trying to do

Comment: Thanks for catching that, both problems were existing and now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use:

```
java.sql.Date.valueOf("2000-01-13")
```

That is, do not use `new` in front of it. By using `new`, you are telling the compiler you want to create a new object. Since [`valueOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) is a static method, you do not need to create an object in order to call it.

Regardless, the reason it does not compile is because `new java.sql.Date.valueOf("str")` is not a valid statement. You would have to say `new java.sql.Date()` with parentheses if you wanted to create a new instance of `Date`, which you do, but by a different means.

Comment: Thanks, apparently my sql database's so-called date was using a varchar as BalusC explained below.